# Debian 8 mysqldump Error

Tags: mysql, debian

I have problem with mysqldump. I have Debian 8 in the latest version. 
When I type `mysqldump -u root -p database > database.sql` 
and then type password - all works fine. But.. when I type `mysqldump -u root -ppassword database > database.sql` I see "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

I need this to write script. Any ideas?

Comment: If you create ~/.my.cnf and add this line:

[client]
password=<password>

Work?

Comment: I tried, but it did not work

Comment: Your password contains a special character, perhaps, like one of `'$"&!*?`?

Comment: Yes, I used special characters. This was a problem. Thank You very much!